# iOS PWA dark theme status bar color

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, manifest

Is there a way to set white background on PWA status bar in dark theme?

In **index.html** I put meta tag:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

The *default* value would work in light mode however is black in iOS dark mode.

Inside **manifest.json** I did this:

```
"theme_color": "#ffffff",
"background_color": "#ffffff"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this line in html `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white">`

Answer (score 0):

apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style "white" is not a valid value for this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30961237)